# What is "cookie-parser" middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, cookie-session

While creating back-end apps with *express.js*, I have used `express-session` and `cookie-session`.

But, recently I found out this `cookie-parser` package on npm. It's pretty popular.

My question is,

What is `cookie-parser` and how is it different from `express-session` or `cookie-session` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cookie Parser` parses the incoming cookies from `request` to JSON value.

Whereas `cookie-session` or `express-session` is to maintain `session` on your server.

When your `frontend` sends a request, if cookies are set up, it will send some cookies based on usage, which by default are hard to interpret by server, so here `cookie parser` will parse those for easy understand ability. Which in turn could be used to create/maintain sessions or Authenticate (Depends upon cookie usage).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to know a user session can be stored in two main ways with cookies: on the server or on the client.

- `cookie-session` *2.0.0* - Stores the session data on the client within a cookie. Set and get cookies. Only use it when session data is relatively small and easily encoded as primitive values (rather than objects). Also, be aware that the cookie data will be visible to the client, so if there is any reason to keep it secure or obscure, then `express-session` may be a better choice.
- `express-session` *1.17.3* - Stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the session data on the server, typically in a database. Set and get cookies.
- `express-session` *<1.5.0* - It uses `cookie-parser` middleware to parse the cookie header and populate the `req.cookies` object. So we must use the `cookie-parser` middleware before `session()`.

To store or access session data, simply use the request property `req.session`.

- `cookie-parser` *1.4.6* -  Parse `Cookie` header and populate `req.cookies` with an object keyed by the cookie names. Only get cookies.

All of them use [cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies) module in their latest version.